# Hadoop mapreduce wordcount program fails with exitcode 9009

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, mapreduce

I have successfully installed Hadoop on windows and trying to run the wordcount program but getting the following error

[image]

My Hadoop version is 2.6.5 and in the error it also says `Exception message: '2.6.5' is not recognized as an internal or external command.` I tried to search for the solution but did not get a logical answer. Please guide me to get through this ?

Comment: That's a Windows error, so doesn't look like you've installed it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem with your code missing something near '2.6.5'as it is taking it as a command separately. you have not provided any insight on your code so I can't guide you accurately.